# Not receiving mail from outside

Tags: ubuntu, email, firewall, port, imap

My DBMail installation can finally receive mail, but from localhost only. I can do telnet localhost 24 and telnet localhost 143, login succesfully. I can also send mail from port 24 to one of my email accounts. But when I send a mail from another server, it will not be delivered to my email account. Good news: I don't receive a mail like `E-mail is not delivered` :). What can I do now?

Comment: I suspect you mean port 25.  That's where SMTP normally "lives".  There's probably an option in your smtp server config like "relay_from", and if that's only set to 127.0.0.0/8, then you'll only be a local mail relay.  You don't wanna set it to 0.0.0.0/8 though, because then the world and his mother can relay mail through you, and you become part of the spam problem.  Instead, you want to enable mail relay for authenticated SMTP connections, Usually done in postfix with cyrus-sasl. Dunno about Dbmail.

Comment: Have you set MX records in the DNS-server?

Comment: No, I meant 24 (lmtp). 25 isn't working at all, and for now not so important. It's just the receiving part; I can't receive extern e-mails, just emails that are sent locally.

Comment: Yes, 2 MX records. And some A record. But I noticed that all subdomains are pointing to this mailserver, but the main server is pointing to another server.

Answer (score 0):

If you send to port 24, you send directly to dbmail. Mails from outside will arrive on smtp-port 25. This means, you have to set a

```
virtual_transport = dbmail-lmtp:127.0.0.1:24
```

directive in postfix's main.cf. You also will need theese directives in main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :), did that, created those SQL files. I'm sure they will work well. But I still can't receive. Is there a way to test Postfix from external connections?

Comment: telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 25

Comment: I normally fire mails to a server to debug and `multital -f` the syslog and mail.err of this mchine. Then you can precisely see, what happens, when the mail arrives. I guess it's a main.cgf typo at all.